# PowerPoint printing using activex control

Tags: c#, activex, powerpoint, activexobject, activex-exe

We have written an ActiveX control using C# to use it in Microsoft PowerPoint.  The control has following Title: 'Test Viewer'.  When I place the control in PowerPoint in edit mode, I see the title in control. But when I print the slide, it show me a big "X" in the print output. Print preview looks proper. I tried using 'PrintDocument' and 'PrintPageEventHandler' in the code but that doesn't seem to hit when printing the slide in PowerPoint edit mode. Can someone throw pointers how to achieve this? Is the data in control need to be communicated in some format?

-Kartlee

Comment: IF we load the control in word and print it, that seems to work fine.

Comment: If I load the control in excel, it seem to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

A similar issue though not with the print can be noticed with powerpoint 2010. When we contacted Microsoft, they confirmed it to be a bug from their side and fixed it.  Please find the hotfix here -

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2553061

-Karthik